# Wildcard ssl -- 2 document roots

Tags: ssl

I currently have a wildcard domain with ssl:
https://*.phppointofsale.com --> /home/phppoint/public_html/PHP-Point-Of-Sale

I would like to do:
https://order.phppointofsale.com --> /home/phppoint/public_html

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible with a wildcard certificate. You can create different vhosts for your subdomains and use the same certificate for them.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts states "As a rule, it is impossible to host more than one SSL virtual host on the same IP address and port. "

I only have 1 IP address for this server and CANNOT get more

Comment: You stopped reading too early. A few lines later, you will read:
"In reality, Apache will allow you to configure name-based SSL virtual hosts... In particular, this will work if the SSL certificate applies to all the virtual hosts. For example, this will work if:

    All the VirtualHosts are within the same domain, eg: one.example.com and two.example.com.

    You have a wildcard SSL certificate for that domain (one where the Common Name begins with an asterix: i.e *.example.com)

Comment: Got it. Also, will a wildcard ssl cert work for the base domain as well? (`https://phppointofsale.com`)

Comment: Yes, wildcard certificates are also valid for the base domain.